# Question on elasticity of materials

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, material-science, elasticity, solid-mechanics

[image]

What I did:
The force applied here is its weight F$=$mg, while m=$\rho l$A, where A = area of cross-section of the wire.
$$\text{Y}=\frac{\text{stress}}{\text{strain}}=\frac{\text{$\rho l$A}/A}{\text{$\Delta l$/}l}$$
$$\Delta l =\frac{\rho l^2}{\text{Y}}$$
So, I get D as the answer, but the actual answer is A. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The force is $mg$ only on the topmost cross section. The tension i.e. the restoring force in the rope varies with height, as the weight it has to support increases with height. You will have to write an equation for extension in an infinitely small cross section at an arbitrary height, and then integrate it from $0$ to $l$